# How can disable emacs' vc integration on mounted volumes?

Tags: emacs, git, sshfs

I'm running Emacs on OSX (Emacs24) and on occasion I have to edit files on a mounted sshfs volume. However, Emacs' vc integration -- git, specifically -- is REALLY slow over sshfs mounts.

I'd like to selectively disable vc-mode, either in configuration or using .dir-locals.el. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

As pmr mentioned, you can remove git from the list of backends.

The [default list of backends](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Customizing-VC.html) is `(RCS CVS SVN SCCS Bzr Git Hg Mtn Arch)`

There are [different ways](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/emacs/emacs_478.html)  to set variables in emacs.

Just editing your `~/.emacs` file and adding the following two lines should do the trick (notice Git is removed from the list)

```
;; Disable git backend to speed up sshfs file load among other things
(setq vc-handled-backends (quote (RCS CVS SVN SCCS Bzr Hg Mtn Arch)))
```

Comment: Why not remove them all?

Comment: `(setq vc-handled-backends (remove 'Git vc-handled-backends))`

Answer (score 0):

I would try modifying the variable **vc-handled-backends** which my version of Emacs describes as:

> vc-handled-backends is a variable defined in `vc-hooks.el'. Its value
>   is (RCS CVS SVN SCCS Bzr Git Hg Mtn Arch)
>
> Documentation: List of version control backends for which VC will be
>   used. Entries in this list will be tried in order to determine whether
>   a file is under that sort of version control. Removing an entry from
>   the list prevents VC from being activated when visiting a file managed
>   by that backend. An empty list disables VC altogether.
>
> You can customize this variable.
>
> This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
>   version 23.1 of Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

I think writing an [around-advice](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Around_002dAdvice.html) for `vc-git-registered` (or even `vc-registered` or `vc-find-file-hook`) would be the best course of action.

In there, you would check the file path or the value of some variable that would be set through `.dir-locals.el`.

Answer (score 0):

```lisp
(setq vc-ignore-dir-regexp
      (format "\\(%s\\)\\|\\(%s\\)"
              vc-ignore-dir-regexp
              tramp-file-name-regexp))
```

assuming you mounted stuff on `/tmp/mnt` it should work by appending another line of formatting `\\|\\(%s\\)` and adding `/tmp/mnt/*` to the list of strings

```lisp
(setq vc-ignore-dir-regexp (format "\\(%s\\)\\|\\(%s\\)\\|\\(%s\\)"
                                     vc-ignore-dir-regexp
                                     tramp-file-name-regexp
                                     "/tmp/mnt/*"))
```

[source](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Frequently-Asked-Questions.html)